# Is it wrong to use English names for days and months?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

It is a fact that the English names of days and months are derived from the names of Roman and Norse gods.

For example Wednesday is derived from Odin, Thursday from Thor, Friday from Freya, Saturday from Saturn, Sunday from Sun, Monday from Moon. Similarly January from Janos, March from Mars, May from Maia, June from Juno, July from Julius, August from Augustus etc.

Is it wrong or haram to use these names? What is different between this and using the names of arab idols like Hubal, Laat, Uzza and Mannat?

Comment: I don't see any relation between this and that. And AFAIK using the names Hubal al-Laat etc. isn't shirk nor haram per se. So what is the point that bothers you actually?